# Pick up button pins

Tags: guitar

Im new to guitar but I have purchased a fender that has a fishman pick up in it. Where the pickup comes out of the bottom hole to plug into is missing the strap button so it falls back inside of the guitar. What am i looking for to replace this all i can find is the screw through ones.

Comment: Google "fishman pickup strap button" or ask at your local music shop.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - Fishman supply the pups and the jack socket so if a part is missing, refer to them - possibly having to buy the whole caboodle again, in order to obtain the missing part.